# How to store cucumber scenario hooks (@Before, @After) in different package

Tags: java, cucumber, junit4, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

We always need to store cucumber scenario hooks on same package where the glue code stored but I want to store it in main framework code so is it possible in cucumber to keep aside scenario hooks from glue code package for better project structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the hook codes anywhere you want, as long as you include the package containing the hook classes in the glue option of the runner class. Add all the relevant packages by delimiting with a comma.

Comment: could you pls look into this question if u have any idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155341/how-to-get-token-without-browser-for-secured-webservice-call-after-login

Comment: Nope got no idea about this query

Comment: Thanks for your help.